# Letter Recognition Error in Azure ML Studio

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm having troubles with a Letter Recognition model I'm creating in Azure ML Studio.

I'm running a few algorithms - Decision Jungle, Neural Network, Decision Forest, Logistic Regression, One vs. All Multiclass, and then I append them using the Add rows method (Neural Network and Desicion Jungle/ Decision Forest and Logistic Regression), until I append them all.

However, appending Decision Forest and Logistic Regression I get the following error:

```
requestId = 9292bc066f51404eb5e0d0d219d3a072 errorComponent=Module. taskStatusCode=400. {"Exception":{"ErrorId":"NotInRangeValue","ErrorCode":"0008","ExceptionType":"ModuleException","Message":"Error 0008: Parameter \"Dataset2(number of columns)\" value should be in the range of [3, 3]."}}Error: Error 0008: Parameter "Dataset2(number of columns)" value should be in the range of [3, 3]. Process exited with error code -2
```

Any advice what should I do? Huge thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs when there is a mismatch of number of columns of the two dataset you are appending.

Looking at the error :

The output of one model is returning rows with 3 columns and other one is having either more or less than 3 columns.

Before this step "Add Rows" step -> Do quick Visualize

[image]

This will give a view of the dataset that you are planning to append.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Ensure for both, the columns numbers are same.

Comment: Makes sense! Thank you Sathya!